# LWC getRecords - Reactive Variable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, ui-record-api

I'm having a hard time getting getRecords to work with a reactive variable passed into the recordIds parameter. It works as expected when passing in a hardcoded list of IDs -- per the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_records) -- but I can't get it to work otherwise.

Here's an example of it working:

```
@wire(getRecords, { 
    records: [
        {
            recordIds: ['00QDH0000091Ha52AE', '00QDH0000091HaA2AU'],
            fields: [CLASSIFICATION_FIELD]
        }
    ]
}) 
wiredRecords({ error, data }) {
    console.log('******* WIRED RECORDS');
    if(error) {
        console.log('*** error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    } else if(data) {
        console.log('*** ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
}
```

On page load, I can see the data getting logged to the console. However, when I try storing the same list in a variable, and pass that into recordIds, the data is not retrieved. I want to maintain a list of Ids in javascript and fire the @wire method whenever that list changes. Here's the code:

```
leadIds = ['00QDH0000091Ha52AE', '00QDH0000091HaA2AU'];

@wire(getRecords, { 
    records: [
        {
            recordIds: '$leadIds',
            fields: [CLASSIFICATION_FIELD]
        }
    ]
}) 
wiredRecords({ error, data }) {
    console.log('******* WIRED RECORDS');
    if(error) {
        console.log('*** error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    } else if(data) {
        console.log('*** ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I also faced the same issue , I think getRecords is not meant for reactive behaviour.

Comment: That's disappointing. Thanks for the response, Rohit.

Comment: Update - Salesforce support says that it IS supported, but that they do not have documentation on it and are not able to point me in the right direction because "our success plan is standard".

Comment: Ohh , can they provide a working example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about):

"Use the $ prefix for top-level values in the configuration object. Nesting the $ prefix such as in an array like ['$accountIds'] makes it a literal string, which is not dynamic or reactive."

Working Example:

```
leadIds = ['00QDH0000091Ha52AE'];

wireObj = [
    {
        recordIds: this.leadIds,
        fields: [CLASSIFICATION_FIELD]
    }
]

@wire(getRecords, { 
    records: '$wireObj'
}) 
wiredRecords({ error, data }) {
    console.log('******* WIRED RECORDS');
    if(error) {
        console.log('*** error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    } else if(data) {
        console.log('*** ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        this.tempLeads = data;
    }
}
```

To make the wire service re-provision data, you have to reassign this.wireObj:

```
test() {
    this.leadIds = ['00QDH0000091HaA2AU'];
    this.wireObj = [
        {
            recordIds: this.leadIds,
            fields: [CLASSIFICATION_FIELD]
        }
    ]
}
```