# LWC - Wire pass dynamic ids to get records method

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, wire

In LWC js i am trying to dynamically pass the ids for getting records of a object.

if i hard code records id like this it works

```
recordIds: ['0687h000002Jim0AAC','0687h000002Jim5AAC'],
```

but if  try like below it doesnt work

```
 recordIds: "$notesData1",



export default class AptsShowNotes extends LightningElement {
    data = [];
    columns = columns;
    richtext = '<h2>Default <s>Value</s></h2>';
    @api notesData = ['0697h000002SQOrAAO','0697h000002SQOwAAO'];
    notesData1 = ['0687h000002Jim0AAC','0687h000002Jim5AAC'];
    @api agreementData;
    @api linkRecords;
    @wire(getRecords, {
        records: [
            {
              recordIds: "$notesData1",
              fields: FIELDS
            }
        ]
    })
```

Any inputs on what's wrong would be super helpful.

Comment: Does this solve your issue - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399012/lwc-getrecords-reactive-variable?noredirect=1#comment574933_399012

Comment: Thank you. I marked mine as duplicate.