# Pre populate fields in lightning-record-edit-form in lwc irrespective of the record page

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

I have a lightning-button which onclick will show a lightning-record-edit-form to create a Case which contains 2 lookup fields

- AccountId (Lookup to Account)
- Opportunity__c (Lookup to Opportunity)

I need to place this lightning component on record page of Opportunity, Account, Contact and Lead.

- If i am on Opportunity Page I want lightning-input to be pre-populated with Opportunity and Account Id available on Opportunity record i am on.
- If i am on Account or Contact Page i want AccountId to be pre populated
- If i am on Lead page i don't want any of these fields to be pre populated.

```html
<lightning-record-edit-form
    object-api-name="Case"
    onsubmit={submitForm}
    onload={handleLoad}
    record-type-id={recordTypeId}
    onsuccess={handleSuccess}
    onerror={handleError}
>

    <lightning-input-field field-name="AccountId" value={accountId} data-name="AccountId"></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Opportunity__c" value={oppId} data-name="oppId"></lightning-input-field>

</lighting-record-edit-form>
```

---

To solve this problem i am fetching the record using getRecord standard method

- ```js
  @track accountId;
  @track oppId;
  @wire(getRecord, {
        recordId: '$recordId',
        optionalFields: [ACCOUNT_ID, CONTACT_ID],
  })
  wiredData;
  ```

Before lightning-record-edit-form is loaded i am setting `accountId` and `oppId` to their respective values if available

- ```js
  if (this.objectApiName === 'Account')
  {
     this.accountId = this.recordId;
  }
  else if (this.objectApiName === 'Contact')
  {
     this.accountId = getFieldValue(this.wiredData.data, ACCOUNT_ID);
  }
  else if (this.objectApiName === 'Opportunity')
  {
    this.accountId = getFieldValue(this.wiredData.data, ACCOUNT_ID);
    this.oppId = this.recordId;  
  }
  ```

This is working fine but it has some problems:

- While using getRecord i need to define fields which i need to fetch with Object Name

  - ```js
      import ACCOUNT_ID from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.AccountId';
      import CONTACT_ID from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.ContactId';
    ```

  Here i am specifying Opportunity, but i need to place this component on various pages other than Opportunity.

I want to know is there any better or Standard approach to achieve this.

Comment: You need to avoid static import of field identifier and you need to construct the field name by accepting an `@api objectAPIName` property on your LWC (this will be automatically populated for Salesforce UI lightning record page usages) and pass field names like `this.objectAPIName + '.AccountId'` to the wire (ensuring the fields are passed as part of a reactive parameter; take a look [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/399012/lwc-getrecords-reactive-variable)).